# Determine the derivative implicitly: $e^x + e^y - \frac{1}{2}x^4y^2= x$

Tags: calculus

I got to $e^x + e^y\cdot y' - 2x^3y^2 + 2y\cdot y' \cdot \frac{1}{2}x^4 = 1$

I'm not sure about the $\frac{1}{2}x^4y^2$ in the original problem and I feel I may have screwed that up in taking the derivative. I do not want to continue solving since I'm not sure I have the step so far correct. Could someone work this out and explain? Thank you

Comment: Can you please check my formatting to make sure it is correct? Thanks

Comment: You have a sign error. It should be $-2y\cdot y'\cdot x^4/2 $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have everything correct so far, up to a minus sign.  (-1 if you are one of my students.)

When we do implicit differentiation, we are essentially using some nice higher level mathematics that tells us that any set of points that satisfy an implicit equality can be written locally as some function.  We may not know what this local function is, but we have some nice theorems that tell us it exists.

What we need to do is make sure we are treating $y$ as a function of $x$.  This is our local function that we do not know!  We are just going to call it $y(x)$.  So, what we will do is replace all of the $y$'s with $y(x)$'s.

Doing so, we get

$$e^x + e^{y(x)} - \frac{1}{2}x^4y(x)^2 = x$$

When we take the derivative w.r.t. $x$ on both sides, we get

$$\frac{d}{dx} e^x + e^{y(x)} - \frac{1}{2}x^4y(x)^2 = \frac{d}{dx} x$$
$$e^x + e^{y(x)} \frac{d}{dx} y(x) - (\frac{4}{2}x^3y(x)^2 + \frac{2}{2}y(x)(\frac{d}{dx} y(x))x^4) = 1$$
$$e^x + e^{y(x)}y^\prime(x) - (2x^3y(x)^2 + y(x)y^\prime(x)x^4) = 1.$$

Since mathematicians are notoriously lazy, we do not need to always write down $y(x)$ and we just write down $y$.  If we do so, we get

$$e^x + e^yy^\prime - (2x^3y^2 + yy^\prime x^4) = 1.$$

You see then that you didn't properly distribute the '-' after you had applied $\frac{d}{dx}$ to both sides.  At this point, you should collect common terms and solve for $y^\prime$.

Answer (score 0):

The key points are the "[Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)" and that we think $y$ as a function of $x$. Hence,
after differentiation, the left side is
$$\frac{\partial (e^x+e^y-\frac{1}{2}x^4y^2)}{\partial x}=e^x+e^y y\prime -\frac{1}{2}(4x^3 y^2+x^4 2y y\prime),$$
and the right side is 
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=1.
$$
Hence, we get
$$e^x+e^y y\prime -\frac{1}{2}(4x^3 y^2+x^4 2y y\prime)=1,$$
i.e., $$e^x+e^y y\prime -2x^3 y^2-x^4 y y\prime=1.$$